# Installing msi applications silently with arguments using PowerShell script fails

Tags: powershell, msi, automated-install

I'm trying to install an msi application silently with a Powershell script with some arguments but it fails. The logs that I get from msiexec is not help full at all.

I believe this is a fault in the arguments in my code:

```
$logFile = "test.log"
$path = "C:\Program Files\MyApp\"
$Arguments = @(
"/i"
('"{0}"' -f $file.fullname)
"/qn"
"/norestart"
 "WIXUI_INSTALLDIR="$path""
 "STARTMENU_SHORTCUT=1"
 "STARTUP_SHORTCUT=1"
 "DESKTOP_SHORTCUT=1"
 "OPERATOR_ROLE=Master"
 "ID=00:00:00:00"
"/l*v"
$logFile
)
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Q1.) Do I need to state all arguments that is used of the msi installer? (Note: I know that the wix installer has default values for all inputs in the gui installer)

Q2.) Is the format of the strings correct?

Q3.) Can I get more logs than what is written here? (Sorry for the format of the log)

```
=== Verbose logging started: 2020-09-17  15:56:13  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:461]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:461]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:461]: ******* RunEngine:
        ******* Product: 
        ******* Action: 
        ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:461]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:461]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:465]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:465]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:466]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (08:D8) [15:56:13:469]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\Developer\Downloads\archive\Binaries\InstallFiles\Windows\
MSI (s) (08:D8) [15:56:13:469]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (08:38) [15:56:13:470]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (08:38) [15:56:13:470]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (08:38) [15:56:13:470]: ******* RunEngine:
        ******* Product: C:\Users\Developer\Downloads\archive\Binaries\InstallFiles\Windows\
        ******* Action: 
        ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (08:38) [15:56:13:470]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Users\Developer\Downloads\archive\Binaries\InstallFiles\Windows\ 3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (08:38) [15:56:13:470]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
MSI (s) (08:D8) [15:56:13:471]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (08:D8) [15:56:13:471]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (08:D8) [15:56:13:471]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (08:D8) [15:56:13:471]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (08:D8) [15:56:13:471]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (08:D8) [15:56:13:472]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:472]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (F0:60) [15:56:13:473]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
=== Verbose logging stopped: 2020-09-17  15:56:13 ===
```

Comment: Ahhh I did not have the fullname of the file list.
$install_files =  Get-ChildItem -path . -filter "*MyApp*" | Select-Object FullName 

This solved my problem

Comment: Great that you were able to solve your problem. Please post your solution as an answer and accept it when you are allowed to do that, otherwise your question stays on the system as unanswered forever.